# Add menu itens in Commerce Kickstart administrative toolbar

Tags: commerce, toolbar

I have worked with default Commerce Kickstart 2 toolbar menu, and I really liked. But now I installed a new module, Commerce Feeds, and I can not access it because there aren't menu entries in toolbar. Is there a way to add menu entries like the one I need in Commerce Kickstart 2 toolbar menu, or I have to back to Drupal 7 administrative toolbar?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're able to modify the Commerce Kickstart 2 admin menu from this path: /admin/structure/menu/manage/management

It's a normal menu created during installation called "Management".